# Algebra, ideals, Cayley-Hamilton

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $M$ be an $n\times n$ Matrix with complex coefficients. Let $$J=\{f\in\mathbb{C}[x]\,\vert\,f(M)=0\}.$$
a) Is J an ideal of $\mathbb{C}[x]$?

b) Let $g\in J$ be a nonzero polynomial of minimal degree. Can the degree of $g$ be equal to $n+1$?

My answer to a): yes, just checking the definition.

My anwer to b): since $\mathbb{C}$ is a field, $\mathbb{C}[x]$ is a principal ideal domain. Therefore, $J=(g)$ for some $g\in\mathbb{C}[x]$ of minimal degree such that $g(M)=0$. I have trouble answering the question, i.e. is it possible, that the degree of $g$ equals $n+1$? I assume it's not possible

Some help would be appreciated, Kind regards.

Comment: You mention the C-H theorem in the title but not elsewhere; in fact C-H is what you need to answer (b).

Comment: thanks David
this is, what I supposed. Does it suffice to say that due to C-H: deg(g)<=n?

Comment: Well it's true that because of C-H, $\deg(g)\le n$. Whether it's sufficient to say that depends on the context - the argument is simple  enough that you could just say that in something written for adult readers, but in a homework problem you might want to explain a bit more...

Comment: *Hint*: The minimal polynomial divides the characteristic polynomial.

Comment: Or maybe: Whether it's sufficient to say that depends on whether you're proving things for the reader's benefit or proving things in order to show that you _can_ prove them...